# CosmosDB SDK class diagram

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, class-diagram

I'm trying to "visualise" all the key classes and relationships from the Java or c# sdk - I haven't seen a class diagram.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Hackolade makes a visualization tool for NoSQL databases and has good support for Cosmos DB.

[Hackolade Website](https://www.hackolade.com/)

Comment: I was after the class diagram of the existing cosmosdb SDK - not sure if this tool can help?

Comment: Visual Studio has class diagramming tools but this doesn't make sense for Cosmos DB since you are simply persisting POCO's in most cases anyway.